# Error while installing build dependency for FreeRADIUS using the command "fakeroot debian/rules debian/control"

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I am in the process of installing build dependency required for FreeRADIUS. One of the command instructed is

`fakeroot debian/rules debian/control`

Upon entering that command, the error shown is:

`/usr/bin/fakeroot: line 175: debian/rules: not found`

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? What was wrong with official deb (and source) packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/freeradius ?

Comment: @N0rbert My Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Also, I was following the instructions from https://wiki.freeradius.org/building/Debian%20and%20Ubuntu, the "installing build dependencies" part.

Comment: By following *all* the instructions.  Like that `cd freeradius-server` or `cd freeradius-server-3.0.x/` from earlier.